# I wrote my first pine script for trading view and I'm getting the error Syntax error at input '='

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

it is complaining about past_ranges[i] = past_ranges[i-1]

```
//@version=5
study("Range Probability")

n = input(title="Number of bars", type=input.integer, defval=100, minval=1)

// Calculate the range of the current bar
my_range = abs(high - low)

// Calculate the range of the last n bars
past_ranges = array.new_float(n, 0.0)
for i = n to 1 by -1
    past_ranges[i] = past_ranges[i-1]
past_ranges[0] = abs(high[0] - low[0])

// Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the past ranges
mean_range = array.avg(past_ranges)
std_dev = array.stdev(past_ranges)

// Calculate the probability of the current range
prob = normcdf(my_range, mean_range, std_dev)

// Plot the probability as a line
plot(prob, title="Range Probability", color=color.blue)`
```

I tried := but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use the array is not the good one for pinescript, please read : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html?highlight=array

To get rid of the error you describe, you should use :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Range Probability")

n = input.int(100, title="Number of bars", minval=1)

// Calculate the range of the current bar
my_range = math.abs(high - low)

// Calculate the range of the last n bars
past_ranges = array.new_float(n, 0.0)
for i = n-1 to 1 by -1
    array.set(past_ranges, i, array.get(past_ranges, i-1))
array.set(past_ranges, 0, math.abs(high[0] - low[0]) )
```

But your code had several other errors.

You should look the pinescript manual https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html
 Like this, your code seems to be IA generated.

Comment: Yes I used ai and tried to fix it. Thanks :)